# On the web page, place a link to the txt file and specify the encoding of the file as utf-8

Tags: html, character-encoding

Now the code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  </head>

    <span lang="en-us"><a href="russian.txt">txt</a> - </span>
```

How to insert charset="utf-8" attribute?

Comment: Unless you intend that different clients can request different character encodings, create the file you want and configure the HTTP server to say which encoding it is using a response header.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the whole document as `UTF-8` with a charset command.

Add this between `<head>` and `</head>`:
`<meta charset="utf-8"/>`